# buffering and sorting items in a stream

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I receive messages from an observable.
These are sometimes not in chronological order, but their value
includes a timestamp that can be used for sorting.

So, we do not know when the stream will end, we know that two entries can be in the wrong order, and we want to deliver the elements in the chronological order. A delay of a second or more is acceptable.

Now, to order the items, i want to buffer and order the elements.

I would need to keep about three entries, sort them and release the first, until a few  miliseconds have passed or a new item arrives.

So there might be this stream:

```
//Time item appears:   example item:
14:01:01               {time: '14:00:00', name: 'olga'}
14:01:02               {time: '14:00:03', name: 'peter'}
14:01:03               {time: '14:00:02', name: 'ouma'}
14:01:05               {time: '14:00:06', name: 'kat'}
14:01:06               {time: '14:00:05', name: 'anne'}
//... more to come
```

And what i need is:

```
//Time item appears:   example item:
14:01:05               {time: '14:00:00', name: 'olga'}
14:01:06               {time: '14:00:02', name: 'ouma'}
14:01:07               {time: '14:00:03', name: 'peter'}
14:01:08               {time: '14:00:05', name: 'anne'}
14:01:09               {time: '14:00:06', name: 'kat'}
// ... more to come
```

So in the example, i would wait for three elements, sort them and release the first (in the example `olga`).
Then, after a few miliseconds, `kat` arrives and would have to be added to the array to be sorted, release the first element (`ouma`) and then again waiting for a certain time to pass or a new element to arrive.

There is the `buffer` and `bufferCount` operator but i can't wrap my head arround how to use those to achieve this, or if there is a more suitable operator maybe.

The only solution i could think of is

- storing the observable results in an array.
- using setInterval as a [`delay`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/delay) to regularly sort and release the *oldest* three elements.
- have flag and counters to determine if nothing happended for a while to then send the remaining sorted elements and terminate the interval
- (re)trigger the interval with every new element, if it is not already set

Here is the Solution i came up with:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-xtjuu8?file=index.ts

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Please also include the JavaScript and some actual examples of the JavaScript Object with the incoming values here in your question.  Note: your "have" and "desire" data is not the same, do you mean to UPDATE the data or are you just missing relevant data from the incoming values sample? With 35k rep you probably have seen the "How to Ask a good question" but gee, here is a link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss The "have" and "desire" Objects are JavaScript Object Examples. Their Content didn't change, their Order Changed.
The Number in the Front is the ficticious time they appear in the stream.
I'll try to make that more clear

Comment: Please, yes also add what you have tried (You did try a sort right?) so we can help you fix it here as that may also give us insight into what to elaborate on in an answer. ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I didn't try anything yet because i was unsure weather there is an rxjs operator based solution. I wouldn't know what operators to use/combine. That's why i am asking.
As i wrote, my only idea would be building my own setTimeout Solution for this, simply sotring all the observable results in an array and then every `n` miliseconds sort it, take the oldest ones and send them out on a subject.
Maybe i'll do that and come back to this question with the solution in order to better showcase what i need.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I think you’re missing the point of the question—OP already stated the stream could be put in an array and sorted. They’re not in an array, it’s an rxjs stream.

Comment: OR perhaps what you have with that comment will inspire an rxjs expert to respond with a fantastic answer :) - I am not that expert :(

Comment: A stream is a stream; it can’t be sorted until it’s complete. IIRC there’s a `toArray`, which is what you already had in mind.

Comment: @AndreschSerj Do you want to emit an array of all received values up to this point?

Comment: @BastianBräu i edited the question, trying to clarify what i want.
I can release items with a delay of up to two seconds, but i need them to be ordered.
So i need to buffer elements and sort them.

Answer (score 1):

This was a fun one!
I played a bit with the `buffer` operator, at first:

```js
// assuming a stream of events like { order: number, name: string }
const event$ = streamOrders().pipe(share())

event$.pipe(
  buffer(event$.pipe(
    map(({ order }) => order),
    startWith(null),
    exhaustMap(order => event$.pipe(order === null ? take(1) : filter(({ order: latest }) => latest === order + 1), take(1))),
  )),
  mergeMap(events => events.sort(({ order: a }, { order: b }) => a - b)),
).subscribe(console.log)
```

If `streamOrders` yields events according to the following table:

| Time item appears | example item |
| --- | --- |
| 14:01:01 | `{ order: 1, name: 'olga' }` |
| 14:01:02 | `{ order: 3, name: 'peter' }` |
| 14:01:03 | `{ order: 2, name: 'ouma' }` |
| 14:01:05 | `{ order: 5, name: 'kat' }` |
| 14:01:06 | `{ order: 4, name: 'anne' }` |

... then here is what you get instead:

| Time item appears | example item |
| --- | --- |
| 14:01:01 | `{ order: 1, name: 'olga' }` |
| 14:01:03 | `{ order: 2, name: 'ouma' }` |
| 14:01:03 | `{ order: 3, name: 'peter' }` |
| 14:01:06 | `{ order: 4, name: 'anne' }` |
| 14:01:06 | `{ order: 5, name: 'kat' }` |

It works by buffering all events until the one that's expected to happen next, then merely sorting and merging in the buffer.
It's pretty neat and gets the job done if we go by your sample input!

Sadly, I realised that if you instead receive an order quite earlier than you should, it would still be emitted out of order: consider the case where you get:
`[1, 10, 3, 4, 5, 2]`... you'd end up with `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10]`; receiving the `1` right away, and the 5 order values, **including `10`** "all at once" when `2` arrives.

---

To circumvent this issue, I had to take another approach, using what's essentially a companion `Subject<number>` to delay each order received until its number is up.

```js
const expected$ = new BehaviorSubject<number | null>(null)
const event$ = streamOrders().pipe(
  delayWhen(({ order }) => expected$.pipe(filter(next => next === null || next === order))),
  share(),
)

event$.pipe(
  map(({ order }) => order + 1), 
  observeOn(asyncScheduler)
).subscribe(expected$)

event$.subscribe(console.log)
```

See it in action [here on StackBlitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-w2tekc?devToolsHeight=33&file=index.ts)

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the effort. Thou this isn't what i was looking for exactly, i think you gave me the idea i needed.
I will add my solution once it is ready.

Comment: Ah, I really thought the second one was it! Thanks for the comment, I'm looking forward to taking a look at your solution! Cheers :)

Comment: I added my solution in a stackblitz to my initial Question. I am unsure if i should make a custom operator out of this and if this could be usefull for anyone. It is kind of an edgy edge case

Comment: @AndreschSerj OMG okay, I get it now; I approached it completely wrong... the "order" property of each of your orders isn't actually a number belonging to a sequence. Okay okay, it all makes more sense now with your updated example. Thanks for following up!

Comment: Now that I get it better, I think there may be another solution, using `debounce` and `buffer`... I'll try to remember to look at it tonight, I don't have the time right now. Cheers!